# Does it make sense to provide different dpi versions of a background image in an ImageView with centerCrop that cover the whole screen?

Tags: android, imageview, android-resources

I have a layout with an `ImageView` that covers the complete width and 3/4 of the height of the screen used for a background image. The `ImageView` is set to `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`, so it scales the image up/down until either the width or height matches the image view bounds and the other dimensions matches or exceeds it.

As the display size of the image is fixed via the image view's layout (which also does not depend on the image's actual dimensions, only on the aspect ratio) I don't need different dpi-version to ensure the image is displayed in the same size across different screen densities.

Also, the `ImageView` scales the image down appropriately (I assume), and I don't have versions with different resolutions that show a different amount of detail. I could of course create my own versions of the image in different resolutions. But the scaling used should be the same the Android system uses.

Given that, is there any advantage to provide different versions for different resolutions or is it enough to just provide the highest resolution version?
Is there a measurable performance benefit in providing the different resolutions and save the system from doing the scaling?

**EDIT**: Of course I can provide different sizes of the background image (e.g. 500x500 and 1000x1000) but almost none of the screens will match it exactly. So it has to be scaled anyway. Is there any advantage in providing different sizes if the scaling has to happen anyway?
In addition, afaik, there are no pixel-based resource specifiers. I could provide a 2160x2160px version for xxhdpi, but that would be much to large for smartphones (only needed for tablets). I could combine that with the size specifiers, e.g. large-xxhdpi, normal-xxhdpi, large-xhdpi, etc. But that would lead to a lot of combinations and a lot of different images sizes, making the .apk-file a lot large than it needs to be (and a lot of effort to maintain it). 
And even than I wouldn't be able to hit the exact pixel resolution for a device, so it seems to be a lot of effort for only very little to no gain (similar to the argument in [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098973/the-sense-of-providing-mdpi-and-hdpi-resources?rq=1)).
Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to have multiple densities for images.

Lets consider that you have image 1000x1000 px and your screen is 1024-512 px. System scales the image up a bit and then centers it.

But what if the screen is like 500x250 px. The system needs to scale the 1000x1000 image a lot down, but if you would have 500x500 there as well, it could use that and do the scale computing a lot faster, saving performance and memory.

The process needs to load the original bitmap into memory and then work with that. So with low density phones the highest density image takes very much of memory before the original can be released.

Comment: 1. as far as I understood it, Android is able to load a system in a lower resolution, not requiring to load the complete image into memory but doing the adaption on the fly. In that case, it shouldn't matter much whether the original image is 1000x1000 or 500x500. So I am wondering whether there is a measurable performance hit at all due to the different scaling factors?

Comment: 2. according to the Android documentation ( https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support ) about Supporting Multiple Screens, the system may actually use higher density version and scale that down because of a better scaling factor. So to achieve a 500x500px image it might use the 1000x1000 image instead of the 750x750 image because a scaling factor of 0.5 can be used in that case. This seems to make it even more difficult to provide the "right" resource for the system to use.

Comment: It may use higher density but always on some level of native code the actual bitmap must be loaded into memory to process that.

Comment: I was under the impression that it is possible to reduce the resolution during reading the image from disk (e.g. Only reading every fourth pixel into memory for a scale factor of 0.5), which means the original image is never completely loaded into memory. In that case all that is slower is the disk access due to a larger file and I'm wondering whether that is noticeable at all.

Comment: Not 100% sure if that's the case with newest API level, but atleast with older you have to load the actual image and do scaling for that.